# Required help in getting logged volumes

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to get description

```
ManagementScope scope = ((WindowsOrc)m_ParentOrc).ConnectWmiScope("root\\WMI");
ObjectQuery testquery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MPIO_GET_DESCRIPTOR");
ManagementObjectSearcher desc = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, testquery);
mpiodescinstances = desc.Get();
```

Above query work properly for 32bit machine, but it is not working for 64bit machine.

Regards,
NewDev

Comment: are you sure which that class (`MPIO_GET_DESCRIPTOR`) exist in the 64 bits OS which you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same puzzle at my work. With the almost same code segment, I got a `ManagementException` saying `"Invalid Class"`.

It turned out that until an MPIO device is configured and a volume is connected, MPIO_GET_DESCRIPTOR WMI class won't be loaded(?)/instantiated. Hope this helps.